# How to search for mathematical results with java stack?

Tags: java, stack

This is my code checking couple brackets in mathematical operations (Implementation Stack).

I want to ask for help how my code can get the result of multiplication, division, addition, subtraction. Can prioritize multiplication and division first. for example the

```
String rumus = "(20 - 2 * 3) * 2 + ((2 + 7) + 20)"
```

can get results `(20 - 2 * 3) * 2 + ((2 + 7) + 20) = 57`. I would be very grateful if you could help me

```
public class Stack4Fix {

public int top = 0;
public char[] data = new char[100];
public boolean q = true;

public void kerja(String rumus) {

    for (int i = 0; i < rumus.length(); i++) { 
        if (rumus.charAt(i) == '(' | rumus.charAt(i) == '{' | rumus.charAt(i) == '[' | rumus.charAt(i) == '<') { 
            data[top] = rumus.charAt(i); 
            top++;
        } 

        if (rumus.charAt(i) == ')' | rumus.charAt(i) == '}' | rumus.charAt(i) == ']' | rumus.charAt(i) == '>') { 
            if (top > 0) { 
                top--; 
                if (rumus.charAt(i) == ')' && data[top] == '(') { 
                    data[top] = '\u0000';
                } else if (rumus.charAt(i) == '}' && data[top] == '{') {
                    data[top] = '\u0000';
                } else if (rumus.charAt(i) == '>' && data[top] == '<') {
                    data[top] = '\u0000';
                } else if (rumus.charAt(i) == ']' && data[top] == '[') {
                    data[top] = '\u0000';
                } else { 
                    q = false;
                }
            } else { 
                q = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void cek() {

    if (data[0] != '\u0000') { 
        q = false;
    }
    if (q == false) { 
        System.out.println("Invalid data");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Valid");
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Stack4Fix rofy = new Stack4Fix();
    String rumus = "(20 - 2 * 3)* 2 + ((2 + 7) + 20)"
    rofy.kerja(rumus); 
    rofy.cek();
}
}
```

Comment: You need to decrement `top` when you "pop" something inside the if-blocks. You might want to combine the conditions with parentheses and `||`-operators since all the blocks are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have a reason not to use the ready-made implementations of stack.

You need to decrement `top` when you pop something inside the if-blocks. You might want to combine the conditions with parentheses and or-operators since all the blocks are identical. Also, the logical or operation has two pipes (`||`), I'm not entirely sure if that matters.

Currently, the element `top` points to will be unassigned, at least for your purposes. The condition `top>0` should use `>=` since there can be something in the zero index. You need to initialize `top` to -1, and increment it before you write something into index `top`.

Comment: "*ready-made implementations of stack*..." What, like `java.util.Stack`? It's terrible.